# Why is pressure or external force needed for combination of electron and proton in plasma phase?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I have studied that after rising temperature matter is converted into plasma. I want to  know that whether in plasma phase nucleon coexist with electron but do not combine until pressure is applied. Why?